# Automated functional testing qt apps in windows

Tags: qt, testing, automation

I'm trying to create scripts that test if some GUI components exist inside a window (combo boxes, check boxes, the state of check boxes, etc.) The app I want to tests is written in QT and running on Windows 7. Its content is created dynamically.

I've tried with swapy/pywinauto, AutoHotkey and AutoIt. But as they rely on standard Windows API calls they are useless for this (need a solution that involves QT).

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [QtTestLib](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qttestlib/qttestlib-manual.html) for integrated solution, or, if you want (and can afford) commercial solutions, I am aware of [squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/) and [kdexecutor](http://freecode.com/projects/kdexecutor).

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that AutoHotKey Windows Spy allows you to see if certain GUI objects exist inside a window. In the example image you see that I held the mouse over a combo box named `ComboBox5`. Are you trying to test at this level?

[image]

The rest can be found here already:[Check if a certain button is existing or not using autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585290/check-if-a-certain-button-is-existing-or-not-using-autohotkey)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Robert, I'm aware of that functionality but the app I want to test is written in QT, and somehow that makes Window Spy only to show the COLOR value of what it's supposed to be under "Now Under Mouse Cursor" and anything else.